# Speed and compatibility of 4GB DDR2 sticks on an Asus P5Q-E motherboard

Tags: memory, compatibility, ddr2

I want to add 8GB of memory (in the form of two 4GB sticks) to a system with an [Asus P5Q-E motherboard](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5QE/#specifications). According to Asus, the motherboard supports

> 4 x DIMM, max. 16GB, DDR2 1200/1066/800/667MHz, non-ECC, un-buffered memory

If I understand correctly, this motherboard will benefit from faster modules up to 800MHz (and modules rated at a higher speed will run at 800MHz). Is this correct? The motherboard is not and will not be overclocked.

When I check the [Crucial memory advisor](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=P5Q-E&Cat=RAM), it recommends [PC2-5300 a.k.a. DDR2-667](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/mpartspecs.aspx?mtbpoid=9A4683FFA5CA7304), even though according to their [module list](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listmodule/DDR2/list.html) they also have a PC2-6400 a.k.a. DDR2-800 model (currently selling for the same price).

Is there a technical reason why I should avoid the DDR2-800 model (either from Crucial or from another supplier)? Would I get a speed benefit over DDR2-667? What compatibility issues do I need to be aware of?